# SQL Server 2014 inconsistent behavior when handling unicode

Tags: sql-server, unicode

My goal is to enforce case-insensitive uniqueness on a column that may contain unicode characters on any unicode planes. But I encountered some inconsistent behavior when testing against SQL Server 2014(build 12.0.4213.0). Here is the test:

```
CREATE TABLE unicodetest1 (
  id int, 
/* this collation is supposed to support all supplementary unicode characters */
  a nvarchar(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_a_1 ON unicodetest1(a);
```

I can insert many single unicode characters, both on BMPs and SMP (Plane 1):

```
INSERT INTO unicodetest1(id, a) VALUES(1, 't'); -- U+0074
INSERT INTO unicodetest1(id, a) VALUES (100, N'');  -- U+1F478
INSERT INTO unicodetest1(id, a) VALUES (101, N'');  -- U+1F479
INSERT INTO unicodetest1(id, a) VALUES (104, N'⭐');  -- U+2b50

SELECT id, a, len(a) FROM unicodetest1;
```

The length of the single character strings is 1, which is expected.

When I concatenate some unicode characters to ascii strings, it still works:

```
INSERT INTO unicodetest1(id, a) VALUES (111, N'test');  -- ok
INSERT INTO unicodetest1(id, a) VALUES (112, N'test');  -- ok
INSERT INTO unicodetest1(id, a) VALUES (113, N'test');  -- ok
```

So far so good.

But, when I insert N'test⭐', I get a duplicate key violation:

```
INSERT INTO unicodetest1(id, a) VALUES (114, N'test⭐');  -- dup

Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 21
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.unicodetest1' with unique index 'idx_a_1'. The duplicate key value is (test⭐).
```

The character "⭐" has a code point U+2b50, it is on BMP!

It seems that SQL Server thinks N'test⭐' and N'test' are identical!

My question is: what makes "⭐" special that it violates uniqueness constraint when it is concatenated to a string?

Thanks

James

Comment: Great question. It seems that it treats all characters in the 2B24-2BFF block as identical. Other than in binary collations, I haven't found one that works as expected.  Oddly, it treats 2B00-2B23 properly.

Comment: Thanks Brian for confirming it. The code point 0x2C00 also works:                                                           
INSERT INTO unicodetest1(id, a) VALUES (106, NCHAR(0x2C00)); is it a sql server bug?

Comment: I won't pretend to understand any of the bizarre reasonings behind most collation practices, but this seems like unexpected behavior to me.  Had I ever run in to it in a production scenario, it would be frustrating to say the least.

Comment: Update:
After talking with MS Support, it turned out that this behavior is "feature-as-designed", i.e. the unicode characters in the block 2B24- 2BFF are treated as identical. A tech blog from 2006 was cited to explain this behavior:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/04/06/sorting-undefined-characters-in-unicode-andor-windows-collation/ 

Practically, it means that SQL Server does not support unicode string comparison (thus no support for sorting, uniqueness enforcement, grouping, etc.) when a non-binary collation is used.

Comment: (con't)
The proposed workaround is to use binary collation. But that would break my code in a big way:
1. I would lose case insensitive string comparison
2. any string functions involving string length now return lengths in bytes instead of in characters.

It does not seem that I have a choice.

It's understandable that not all unicode characters have linguistic sorting semantics. But if undefined, in my opinion, SQL Server should fallback to binary comparison, instead of treating them identical.